# Distribution of $Y=\frac{X}{|X-1|}$ when $X$ is uniform on $[0,2]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution in $[0,2]$. Find the distribution of $Y=\frac{X}{|X-1|}$.

I wrote:

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{X}{|X-1|}\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{|X-1|}{X}\geq \frac{1}{y})=\mathbb{P}(|X-1|\geq \frac{x}{y})=\mathbb{P}[(X\geq \frac{y}{y-1},X>1)\cup (X\leq \frac{y}{y+1},X<1)]$

where, for example, $\mathbb{P}(X\leq \frac{y}{y+1},X<1)=\int_{0}^{\operatorname{min}(1,\frac{y}{y+1})}\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{2y+1}{y+1}]$. Unfortunately it seems that I'm out of the way. Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't think that $4$th equality sign is correct. What is $x$?

Comment: @openspace Why not?

Comment: What is $x$ and why it becomes $y$?

Comment: @openspace I don't understand. I did $\mathbb{P}[(X-1\geq \frac{x}{y}, X>1)\cup (1-X\geq \frac{x}{y},X<1)]$. Could you explain better?

Comment: $X$ and $x$ in your notation is the same or not?

Comment: $X$ is the variable, $x$ is the value assumed by the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right path! I think it's best to plot $Y$ in order to see which is the support of the distribution.

[image]

As you probably have already noticed, the support of $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

Let $x\sim\mathcal{U}[0,2]$ and $Y=\frac{X}{|X-1|}$

$$
F_{Y}(y)=P\left(Y\leq y\right)=P\left(\frac{X}{|X-1|}\leq y\right)=P\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\leq y,X>1\right)+P\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\leq y,X\leq 1\right)
$$

Let's compute each term separetly:
$$
P\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\leq y,X>1\right)=P\left(X\leq \frac{y}{1-y},X>1\right)
$$
$$
P\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\leq y,X\leq 1\right)=P\left(X\leq \frac{y}{1+y},X\leq 1\right)=P\left(X\leq \frac{y}{1+y}\right)
$$
Now you have to compute those integrals. But bear in mind that the limits of integration may vary according to different values of $y$.

Please let me know if there was something I did not explain properly. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain me the last equivalence (where remains only $\mathbb{P}(X\leq \frac{y}{y+1})$)? P.S.: For the other probability the result is $1-\frac{y}{y^2-1}$.

Comment: Sure! Notice that since $y\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$ then $\frac{y}{y+1}<1$ and thus the upper bound on your integral is just $\frac{y}{y+1}$ since $\min\left\{\frac{y}{y+1},1\right\}=\frac{y}{y+1}$. Was that clear enough?

Comment: btw Im a big fan of Totti